# How to load array of strings with tab delimiter in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a text file with tab delimiter and I am trying to print first column as id and remaining array of strings as second column names.

consider below is the file to load:

```
cat file.txt;
1   A   B
2   C   D   E   F
3   G
4   H   I   J   K   L   M
```

In the above file, first column is an id and the remaining are names.

I should get the output like:

```
id           names
1            A,B
2            C,D,E,F
3            G
4            H,I,J,K,L,M
```

If names are split with delimiter `,`, then I am getting the output by using below commands:

```
test = load '/tmp/arr' using PigStorage('\t') as (id:int,names:chararray)
btest = FOREACH test GENERATE id, FLATTEN(TOBAG(STRSPLIT(name,','))) as value:tuple(name:CHARARRAY);
```

But for the array with delimiter `('\t')`, I am not getting them because it's considering only the first value in the column 2 (i.e, names).

Any solution for this?

Comment: Are your trying to concatenate all fields starting from the second column? or Are you trying to split the output?

Comment: Hi Benjamin,Thanks for your reply. Let me rephrase my question. Say in my feed file with tab delimiter, i have one row  with data as "2   C   D   E   F".  I need to load this data from hdfs to a variable in grunt shell using pig. I used  as grunt> data = load '/tmp/file.txt' using PigStorage('\t') as (id:int,name:chararray). I want  to store the data as like 2 in the ID field and ( C,D,E,F) as array value in the field called "name". I'm not sure how to load the set of values C D E F into a single field(array) called "name". since it's tab delimited,im not able to store the data as array.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this:

When using PigStorage('\t') in the load, the file should have tab delimiter. So the number of tab used in a line that many coloumns(+1) is created. This is how it works.
But you have a trick
You can change the default delimiter and use some other delimiter to load the file like comma and then you can have the names in commaseperated.
It will work for sure
Input file sample

```
1,A B
2,C D   E   F
3,G
4,H I   J   K   L   M
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I thought I can create an Array with tab delimiter without using any other tab delimiter.Now I got the point.Thanks once again.